# "The sum and substance of this poem { is / are} ..." -- what is the rule?

Tags: grammaticality

There have been a question, find the error in the following sentence,

> The sum and substance of this poem is as follows.

I think the problem is the *is* in ***is** as follows*, because *sum and substance* are two things. But somebody told me that when we say something like *A and B*, the whole phrase acts as a singular thing and we should say *A and B* ***is***. But this sounds odd.

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiom.  Another well-known combination of the same nature is "part and parcel".  Both are used with singular verb forms.

Comment: So in general I should use _are_, but here _is_ is right because it is an idiom.

Comment: @user31782: You might do better to just forget about this "idiom". Personally, I think it's [well past its sell-by date](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sum+and+substance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csum%20and%20substance%3B%2Cc0). But as Victor says, if you *are* going to use it, you should stick to the *singular* verb form *(**is**)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I couldn't understand. Should I use _A and B is_ or _A and B are_? Are you talking about the idiom only?

Comment: @user31782: Yes, I'm only saying *sum and substance* is a dated usage. But plenty of others (such as Victor's *part and parcel*) are still in common use. In cases like this (where the two nouns *always* go together as a "fixed expression"), you should use a singular verb.

Comment: [This chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sum+and+substance%2Cpart+and+parcel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csum%20and%20substance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpart%20and%20parcel%3B%2Cc0) gives a clear picture of how *sum and substance* has gone out of fashion, whereas *part and parcel* has stayed in common use for the past couple of centuries. If someone really did set your example text as an exam question supposedly containing an "error", they're in the wrong job.

Comment: For the record, the [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sum%20and%20substance) says it was first recorded 1585-1595, and the cited usage in *The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary* is the somewhat antiquated & legalistic: *Of which if you should here disfurnish me, You take the **sum and substance** that I have.* (i.e. - if you take *this* away from me, you take everything I have).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes it was asked in SSC-CGL-2015 exam. This exam is conducted every year nation-wide for the selection of Grade-B officers in India. Unfortunately this exam always has many wrong questions. In the exam there is also an option to mark _no-error_. But asking questions from outdated English is not a good thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In general do we always consider "A and B" as singular in non-fixed expressions too? E.g. _"The length and breadth of this block is as follows._ I'm not sure whether I should say _are as follows_ or _is as follows_.

Comment: @user31782: There's no "in general" for the basic "A and B" construction itself - it depends on whether *in context* the two elements are thought of as being part of a single "whole" or not. Which isn't likely with your *length and breadth* example, given you're presumably about to continue the utterance by stating individual values for each (thus emphasizing that they're two *different* things).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Means if were to say "The length and breadth of this block _is_ quite large" then I should use _is_, and if I were to say "The length and breadth of this block _are_ 5 metre and 6 metre respectively" then I should say _are_.

Comment: @user31782: There wouldn't be universal agreement in every case (and I suspect *on average* BrE is more tolerant than AmE of the singular in many contexts). Personally I *wouldn't* use singular even for your second example (because they are "literally" two distinct measurements), but I'd have no problem at all with a more figurative usage such as *The depth and breadth of your knowledge **is** impressive*.